# jQuery :closest() CSS selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Need a selector equivalent of function `$.fn.closest()` e.g.

```
$('.wrapper:eq(0)>h1>strong:closest(.wrapper)')
```

implementation should return `.wrapper` element, which is the first on the page and contains `h1`, which consequently contains `strong` element.

Actually, an example above is only an example. In real world, I need `$.fn.draggable` to set up a dynamic `containment` property.

---

## UPDATE

To bring things more clear: there are (for ex.) tree wrappers `div.wrapper` on the page followed one by the other. Each wrapper is connected to sibling wrappers as a sortable area. Sortable items are `div.sub-wrapper`, and are placed over one of the wrappers, so, they can be moved to the other wrappers. Each sortable item has a child element `div`, which is the draggable element. What do I actually need is to set the `draggable.options.containment` of the latter to the very parent wrapper the latter (draggable) element currently located at by the moment. The main problem is that if I will register the containment like

```
{containment: $('div.draggable').closest('div.wrapper')}
```

then it won't work correctly if I will move the `div.sub-wrapper` to the other `div.wrapper` - the containment element stays the same - an old one `div.wrapper` the draggable was previously located at.

Comment: CSS selectors don't have the privelege of selecting ancestors.

Comment: I'm afraid this is quite unclear. Do you really need a **CSS** selector, or just a jQuery call that will find the element (which means you could use jQuery-isms in it, and/or subsequent calls to narrow the result set)? Do you need what you've said in the paragraph starting with "implementation should..." or what you need in the last paragraph, which don't seem to be the same thing? Separately: What have you done to solve the problem? What has your research turned up? What did/didn't you find in [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) that did/didn't help?

Comment: A [mcve] would **really** help. Describing code/markup is always much less clear than showing an MCVE of that code/markup actually showing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking you want to use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```
$('.wrapper:has(>h1>strong)')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I am searching for. Thx for link to the docs, I know how does that function work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean it does not do what you want.... Maybe html with what needs to be matched would help. So if you have two wrappers than you need to put the has on inner one.... Or live with the fact it needs to be done in two calls, not everything needs to be one line.

Comment: I have updated the question to make things more clear. That solution won't help me because the `.wrapper` element is changed dynamically. So, what do I have - is a DOM-element which is draggable. I have it's pointer in a variable. And I need to tell the `jQuery.fn.draggable` library to set the `containment` property (which is an HTMLElement-typed) to the currently closest `.wrapper` of itself. The simpliest solution I am supposing - is using the selector `:closest(.wrapper)`, but that is impossible due to `:closest()` selector doesn't exist, so, I need to implement it somewise.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, I suspect you need to initialize the draggables individually rather than as a set:

```
$("selector-for-your-draggables").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.draggable({
        // ...other options here...
        containment: $this.closest(".wrapper") // or .sub-wrapper, I couldn't
                                               // tell from the description
    });
});
```

You've talked about the parent it's in "at the moment." I can't make out what you mean by that, but if the element you want the draggable contained to changes, you'll need an `"options"` call to update `containment` when that happens.